# How to prevent a resolver from calling the same multiple http get requests

Tags: angular, angular-resolver

My app has several routing re-directions that each on of them triggering the `FooResolverService`, and each resolve invocation calls a `FooService`'s method of `GetFoos` http get method (so my resource api is being requested multiple times with the same request).

How to allow only for the first invocation of the `resolve` to actually call the resource api via the `FooService`?

```
export class FooResolverService implements Resolve<FooModel[]> {
  constructor(    
    private fooService: FooService
  ) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    console.log("resolve");
    return this.fooService.getFoos();
  }
}
```

`FooService`:

```
getFoos() : FooModel[] {        
    if (this.foos.length === 0) {
        this._foosAPIService.fetchFoos().subscribe(foos => 
        {
            this.setFoos(foos);
        });
    } 
    else {
        return this.foos;
    }
}

setFoos(foos: FooModel[]) {
    this.foos = foos;
}
```

`FoosAPIService`

```
fetchFoos() : Observable<FooModel[]> {
    return this._httpClient
        .get<FooModel[]>(
            this._configService.resourceApiURI + 'foos/'      
        );
}
```

`Routes`

```
const routes: Routes = [  
  { path: '', component: FoosComponent, children: children},
  { path: ':id', component: FoosComponent, children: children, resolve: [FoosResolverService]}
];
```

Comment: You'd have to add caching somewhere, probably in FooService so all consumers benefit from it.

Comment: You can use rxjs `shareReplay()` operator in pipe() of `http.get()`

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the tips, I've posted an answer of my own by your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggested, I've ended up caching the `Observable` itself (instead of caching the results), with the help of `shareReplay()`:

`FoosAPIService`:

```
fetchFoos(filter: string) : Observable<EventFoo[]> {
    if (this.fetchFoos$[filter]) {
      return this.fetchFoos$[filter];
    }

    this.fetchFoos$[filter] = this._httpClient
      .get<FooModel[]>(
        this._configService.resourceApiURI + 'events/'
      )
      .pipe(
        shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
      );
    
    return this.fetchFoos$[filter];
}
```

`Service`:

```
fetchFoos(filter: string) : void {        
    this.foosSubscription = this._foosAPIService.fetchFoos(filter)
        .subscribe(foos => 
        {                
            this.setFoos(foos);
            this.foosSubscription.unsubscribe();
        });
}
```